# Creating a Fibonacci sequence function in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that prints a list of the first 4 numbers in the Fibonacci sequence, the first 10 numbers in the Fibonacci sequence, and then "the first -4" numbers in the Fibonacci sequence. The "-4" numbers in the Fibonacci sequence should return an empty list because there is no "-4" numbers in the sequence. I need the function to print the 3 lists as an end result in the main() function. Here is my code so far, I'm new to functions so any help would be appreciated.

```
fn = []

def F(n):
    i = 0
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(0,n):
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp + b
    fn.append(b)
    i = i + 1
    return fn


main():
    print F(4)
    print F(10)
    print F(-4)
```

Comment: `a, b = b, a + b` would be more pythonic. Further, if you want the function to handle negative numbers as argument, you should add a condition that takes care of it at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function for generating Fibonacci numbers is correct except the global variable `fn = []` should be declared within the function body. Also, as suggested in the comment by @alfasin, `a, b = b, a + b` is more Pythonic.

```
def fib_list(n):
    a = 0; b = 1; fib_list = []
    if n <= 0:
        return 
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
        fib_list.append(b)
    return fib_list
```

The other problems I could find with your code:
*  `print` is not a statement in Python 3.x.x, it is a function instead, i.e. `print F(4)` should be `print(F(4))`
* `main():` should be changed to `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: What do you mean by "if__name__==__main__"? I've never seen this format for a main function before

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__:` is not a function. It specifies what code to execute if the `python_file.py` is executed from the shell like `python python_file.py`. In your code fragment it was unclear if that is what you wanted, or you wanted a function called `main`. If the latter is the case, then you should declare it as `def main():`